# Not getting expected output - paper folding problem

Tags: python

Create a function that returns the thickness (in meters) of a piece of paper after folding it n number of times. The paper starts off with a thickness of 0.5 mm.

```
def num_layers(a):
    Sum = 0
    for i in range(-1, 100):
        for k in range(1, a+1):
            Sum += 2**i
            if k == a+1:
                break
    return (Sum)/1000
```

Where am I going wrong? I have written it according to the logic, but I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Firstly, make sure you have the right indenttion in your code. Second, dont name your variables `Sum`, thats a bad practice. Why do you have a static range of `(-1, 100)`, nowhere in your task it is said to fold it 100 times. You do not need 2 ranges, each iteration your sum is simply `sum*2`, not `2**i`, you are raising 2 to the power of `i`.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Thanks for the advice.Will keep them in mind and work accordingly..As for the code logic..I was doing 2**-1+2(power 0)+2(power 1)+...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
def fn(a):
    res = 0.5
    for _ in range(a):
        res *= 2
    # return res for mm
    return res / 1000 # for meters
```

Where `a` is the number of folds. With each fold you have to multiply the thickness of the current thickness by 2.

Adjust to your desired metric by dividing the `res`.

Comment: Btw, multiplying by 2, `a` times is the same thing as just multiplying by `2**a` so really this could be reduced to: 


```
def fn(a):
    return (res * 2**a) / 1000
```